# Do these initial value problems have a unique maximal solution? Why/Why not? What is a/the largest domain for the ODEs in the IVPs?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problems:** Explain why the following IVPs have a unique maximal solution. Assume the ODEs are defined on the largest possible open connected set $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$. Identify such D.
>
> 1. $x' = t^3 - x^3, x(0) = 2$
> 2. $x' = 3t - (x-1)^{1/3}, x(0) = \ln(1+e)$
> 3. $x' = \sin(t) - \tan(x), x(0) = 0$

---

> **Definition**: Let $x = x(t)$. A **solution of the first order ODE** $x' = f(t,x)$, where $f$ is defined on some domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ s.t. $D$ is open and connected, is a differentiable function $\varphi$ on some interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ s.t.
>
> 1. $(t, \varphi(t)) \in D \ \forall t \in I$
> 2. $\varphi'(t) = f(t, \varphi(t)) \ \forall t \in I$

---

> **Uniqueness Theorem**: If $f$ and $f_x$ are continuous on a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $(\tau, \xi) \in D$, then there exists a unique maximal solution $\varphi$ of $x' = f(t,x)$ defined on some interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ s.t. $\tau \in I$ and $\varphi(\tau) = \xi$

---

What I tried:

> 1. $x' = t^3 - x^3, x(0) = 2$

$(0,2) \in D = \mathbb R^2$

$f = t^3 - x^3$ is continuous in $D = \mathbb R^2$

$f_x = -3x^2$ is continuous in $D = \mathbb R^2$

---

> 2. $x' = 3t - (x-1)^{1/3}, x(0) = \ln(1+e)$

$(0,\ln(1+e)) \in D = \mathbb R \times (1,\infty)$

$f = 3t - (x-1)^{1/3}$ is continuous in $D = \mathbb R \times (1,\infty)$

$f_x = - (1/3)(x-1)^{-2/3}$ is continuous in $D = \mathbb R \times (1,\infty)$

---

> 3. $x' = \sin(t) - \tan(x), x(0) = 0$

$(0,0) \in D = \{(t,x) | x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)\}$

$f = \sin(t) - \tan(x)$ is continuous in $D = \{(t,x) | x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)\}$

$f_x = -\sec^2(x) = -(\tan^2(x) + 1)$ is continuous in $D = \{(t,x) | x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)\}$

---

Did I go wrong somewhere?

Are the $D$'s open and connected?

We didn't have any topology courses, and our real analysis only covered $\mathbb R$.

Comment: $(x-1)^{-2/3}$ is not continuous in $\mathbb R^2$. In problem 2., $D=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R_+$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Oh shoot. Thanks. You mean $D = \mathbb R \times (1, \infty)$ or $D = \mathbb R \times (-\infty,1)$? Post as answer?